# Interpreting log likelihood

Tags: r

I have difficulty interpreting some results. I am doing an hierarhical related regression with `ecoreg`. If I enter the code I receive output with oddsratio's, confidence ratio's and a 2x maximized log likelihood.

However, I do not fully understand how to interpreted the 2x maximized log likelihood. As far as I know log likelihood is used as a convenient way to calculate a likelihood and it calculates the value of the parameters based on the outcomes. But I do not understand if a higher or lower value is better. I looked at several online sources e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343093/what-is-log-likelihood, but I am still stuck.

Below the outcome I receive:

`Call:
eco(formula = cbind(y, N) ~ deprivation + meanIncome, binary = ~fracSmoke + 
    soclass, data = dfAggPlus, cross = cross)`

`Aggregate-level odds ratios: 
                   OR        l95        u95
(Intercept) 0.0510475 0.03837276 0.06790878
deprivation 0.9859936 0.88421991 1.09948134
meanIncome  1.0689951 0.95574925 1.19565924`

`Individual-level odds ratios:
                OR       l95      u95
fracSmoke 3.124053 2.0761956 4.700765
soclass   1.001050 0.9930815 1.009083`

`-2 x log-likelihood:  237.4882`

So, how should I interpreted a value of 237.4882 compared to an outcome of 206 or 1083? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Wrong site for the question. You'd better try Cross Validated.

Comment: It was a cross-post of of [Interpreting log likelihood](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214556/interpreting-log-likelihood)

Answer (score 1):

A higher value of likelihood or log-likelihood (since log is an increasing function) is better, since it says that the parameters are more likely given the observation/data.

I suggest the wiki article on maximum likelihood estimation for further reference. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood)